# How to pass click handler to specific map layer?

Tags: reactjs, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to access the properties of a specific ArcGIS WebMap layer.
I've attached a click handler to the WebMap React component, but I can only access the mapPoint.latitude and mapPoint.longitude values (in the event) from the base map.

For example, from layer 4 I want to access the custom value for 'Location Name' when I click on specific areas of the map.

Simplified example code:

```
clickHandler = e => {
  console.log(e.mapPoint.latitude + ", " + e.mapPoint.longitude);
};

...

<WebMap
  viewProperties={{
    center: [ this.props.latitude, this.props.longitude ],
    zoom: 12
  }}
  mapProperties={{ basemap: "streets" }}
  onClick={e => this.clickHandler(e)}
  id="9a9a9a9aaaccc1234"
/>
```

Comment: Are you binding this.clickHandler somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Rahul - the clickHandler works fine, I just want to know if it's possible to attach it to a specific layer.

Answer (score 1):

As you found, the click handler is only going to give you the mapPoint coordinates.

In order to get information from a specific Featurelayer at that mapPoint you need to do either an [IdentifyTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-IdentifyTask.html) or [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-QueryTask.html) on the FeatureLayer of interest, using those coordinates from the mapPoint as the query geometry. See the examples from the documentation on how precisely to do this.